# haskell - own version inits - list comprehensions

Tags: haskell

Look at following version of inits:

```
inits4 :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits4 [] = [[]]
inits4 (x:xs) = []:[x:ys | ys <- inits4 xs]
```

I know how to work comprehension list, but this case is horrible. Could somebody try to explain it, please ?

Comment: Where is this code from? Does it work? What don't you understand?

Comment: Try to compute `inits4 [1,2,3]` by hand -- it will not take very long. Start by computing `inits4 []`, then `inits4 [3]`, then `inits4 [2,3]`, then `inits4 [1,2,3]`. Every step is used in the next one.

Comment: inits4 [] = [[]], inits4[3] = []:[3:ys | ys <- inits4[]] = []:[3:ys | ys<-[[]] ] =[]:[3:[[]] ].

It doesn't match, 3:[[]] :(

Comment: @HaskellFun You're almost there. However `y<-[[]]` means that `y` is an element of `[[]]`, so the only choice is `y=[]`. Hence we get `inits4 [3] = ... = []:[3:[]] = [ [], [3] ]` which is the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the recursive case, suppose that we want to compute

```
inits4 [x1,...,xn] =
[ [], [x1], [x1, x2], [x1, x2, x3], ..., [x1, ..., xn] ]
```

We start by computing `inits4` on the tail of the list. By induction, we get

```
inits4 [x2,...,xn] =
[ [], [x2], [x2, x3], ..., [x2, ..., xn] ]
```

How to turn the above into the wanted result. Well, we need to add `x1` to every list in the list of lists. We can do that with a list comprehension

```
[x1:y | y <- inits4 [x2,...,xn]] =
[ x1:[], x1:[x2], x1:[x2, x3], ..., x1:[x2, ..., xn] ] =
[ [x1], [x1, x2], [x1, x2, x3], ..., [x1, x2, ..., xn] ] =
```

That's almost what we wanted! We only add to add the empty list:

```
[] : [x1:y | y <- inits4 [x2,...,xn]] =
[ [], [x1], [x1, x2], [x1, x2, x3], ..., [x1, x2, ..., xn] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You say

```
inits4 :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits4 [] = [[]]
inits4 (x:xs) = []:[x:ys | ys <- inits4 xs]
```

I hope you can figure out the first case yourself. The second can be translated mechanically to `do` notation:

```
inits4 (x : xs) = [] : do
  ys <- inits4 xs
  return (x : ys)
```

This we can desugar to

```
inits4 (x : xs) =
  [] : (inits4 xs >>= \ys -> return (x : ys))
```

We have a law that

```
m >>= \a -> return (f a) = fmap f m
```

so

```
inits4 (x : xs) =
  [] : fmap (x :) (inits4 xs)
```

Since `inits4` produces a list, `fmap = map`, and the you should be able to work the rest out.

---

Note that this implementation suffers from a serious efficiency problem and should not be used in real code. The simplest implementation with unconditionally asymptotically optimal performance is probably

```
inits xs = [] : zipWith (\i _ -> take i xs) [1..] xs
```

Comment: @HaskellFun, it's a generalization of  `return`. I made it consistent now.